# PHP de Wordpress!

Tags: php, wordpress-theme

Muito boa tarde, sou novo aqui no stackoverflow e tenho uma dúvida relacionada a um tema de wordpress, tenho a seguinte programação em php:

```
     if ($i == 0 || ($i % 3 == 0)){ 
        echo '<div class="item '.esc_attr($active).'"><div class="row">';
                                        $open = 1;
                                    }
                                    ?>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4  col-md-4">
      <div data-link="<?php echo esc_js(esc_url($e['permalink'])); ?>" class="qw-itemscarousel-item">
        <div class="row">                                            
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 qw-hideoverflow qw-dynamiccovers">
         <div class="qw-cover-fx-container">
                <?php
                    echo '<img src="'.esc_url($image).'" class="img-responsive hidden-xs" alt="'.esc_attr($page->post_title).'">';
                                                        ?>
                    <div class="qw-cover-actions qw-animated qw-verydark">
                        <a href="#" class="qticon-play" data-addtoplaylyst data-releasedata="<?php echo esc_js(esc_url(add_query_arg( array('qw_get_json_data' => '1'), $e['permalink'] )));?>"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo esc_attr__('Add to playlist','_s'); ?>"></a>
                                <a href="#" class="qticon-search qwjquerycontent" data-qwjquerycontent="<?php echo esc_js(esc_url($e['permalink']));?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo esc_attr__('Tracklist','_s'); ?>"></a>
                                   </div>

                         <div class="qw-itemscarousel-text qw-cover-fx qw-animated qw-negative">
                            <p class="qw-itemscarousel-title qw-caps">
                                  <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo esc_attr__('Go to page','_s'); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url($e['permalink']); ?>"> <?php echo esc_attr($e['title']); ?></a>
                                 </p>
                                     <div class="qw-separator-mini hidden-xs qw-animated"></div>
                                  <p class="qw-itemscarousel-detail qw-small qw-caps"> 
                                                                <?php echo esc_attr($e['releasedate']); ?>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php 
                                    if  (($i+1) % 3 == 0){ 
                                        echo '</div></div>';
                                        $open = 0; 
                                        $col++;
                                    } 
                                    $active = ''; 

                                    $i ++;

                                endwhile;endif;
                            //}/*foreach*/ 






                        if(isset($open)){
                          if($open == 1) { 
                            ?> 
                            </div> </div>
                            <?php 
                            $col++; 
                          }
                        } 

                        ?>
                    </div>                 
                </div>

                </div>              
            <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
            wp_reset_query();
```

Que me retorna um carrossel com 3 imagens do mesmo tamanho, de acordo com: col-xs-12 col-sm-4  col-md-4!

Minha questão é, eu gostaria de mudar esta forma como aparecem as imagens, gostaria que aparecessem assim:

[grid http://marcelotakano.com.br/downloads/grid_carrossel.jpg](http://marcelotakano.com.br/downloads/grid_carrossel.jpg)

Cuja programação seria:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="width:100%; height:400px; background: blue;" class="col-md-12">
            <span>IMAGEM 1 GRANDE</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background: red;" class="col-md-12">
            IMAGEM 2 PEQUENA
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background: yellow;" class="col-md-12">
            IMAGEM 3 PEQUENA
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background: silver;" class="col-md-12">
            IMAGEM 4 PEQUENA
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background: gray;" class="col-md-12">
            IMAGEM 5 PEQUENA
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém não estou conseguindo inserir esta programação dentro do código, pois ele me retorna esse grid novo infinitamente.

Será que alguém entendeu o meu problema e pode me ajudar?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: se colocar if ($i == 0 || ($i % 5 == 0)){...  e lá no final if  (($i+1) % 5 == 0){.... o que acontece?

Comment: Fazendo isso, retornar um carrossel com 5 itens, baseado no grid col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4!, meu problema é conseguir mudar esse grid e fazer aparecer os itens da forma que eu gostaria, que nem na imagem acima @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Veja se entendi, fazendo a modificação retornam 5 itens (carrossel com 5 imagens) porém não na forma que vc quer. Se verdadeiro então tem que atuar no CSS.

Comment: seria mais fácil de vc reescrevesse todo o código.

Comment: seria mais fácil de vc reescrevesse todo o código. Pelo que eu entendi, vc terá 5 imagens por slide [1 grande + 4 pequenas]
A lógica é você iterar sob o array de posts, fazendo um validação simples, para saber qual quadro deve ser inserido.
A ideia aqui é utilizar o resto da divisão do index do array por 5.
sendo que se o resto lhe dará qual o tipo quadrado ele será [Grand ou Pequeno]
Sendo que:
[0] = grande
[1,2,3,4] = pequeno.